# What's the difference of Event and Lock in python threading module?

Tags: python, blocking, python-multithreading

Does `Event` and `Lock` do the same thing in these scenes?

```
class MyThread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(event):
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        self.event.wait()
        # do something
        self.event.clear()
```

another:

```
class MyThread2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(lock):
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        # do something
        self.lock.release()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you wait on an event, the execution stalls until an `event.set()` happens

```
event.wait()  # waits for event.set()
```

Acquiring a lock only stalls if the lock is already acquired

```
lock.acquire() # first time: returns true
lock.acquire() # second time: stalls until lock.release()
```

Both classes have different use cases. [This article](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/) will help you understand the differences.

Answer (score 14):

Practically speaking, I found the difference between Event versus Lock in python to be:

- An event can have many waiters and when the event is set or fired, ALL these waiters will wake up.
- A lock can have many waiters and when the lock is released, only one waiter will wake up and as a result will acquire the lock.

There could still be more differences, but the above is the most obvious to me.